# Closest value in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datatable

I am currently trying to find the value of a column by comparing the value of another column with a reference number.

Let me explain:

I have a DataTable with 2 columns.

```
ID    DATA
1     120
2     200
3     -60
4     478
```

I want to find the ID of the DATA closest from 0.

In this case the correct value will be -60 and the ID 3

I actually do that

```
int closestId = dtQueryLambda.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<double> ("DATA") > 0 || 
                                                        x.Field<double>("DATA") < 0) 
    .Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("ID"))
    .First();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What about getting the absolute values and then getting the min?

Comment: Because i'll in the next step, find in an other DataTable find the index of the data where the target number will be the data of the previous result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
double baseValue = 0; // or something else
int closestId = dtQueryLambda.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dr => new
    {
        Id = dr.Field<int>("ID"),
        Diff = Math.Abs(dr.Field<double>("DATA") - baseValue)
    })
    .Aggregate((a, b) => b.Diff < a.Diff ? b : a).Id;
```

The above is an efficient standard LINQ To Objects approach. With [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/) it's even simpler:

```
int closestId = dtQueryLambda.AsEnumerable()
    .MinBy(dr => Math.Abs(dr.Field<double>("DATA") - baseValue))
    .Field<int>("ID");
```

Comment: The second solution is the best i think, but i can't use MinBy function on a EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>

Comment: Why not? It's implementing `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, so any extension method should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the absolute value and then select the first

```
var closestId = dtQueryLambda.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Field<double>("DATA")))
    .Select(x => x.Field<Int32>("ID"))
    .First();
```